# Unable to delete item with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to do simple ajax delete. The problem is that nothing happen when I click on trash button. I'm very new in ajax and jquery and doesn't know even how to debug this.

In the console under tab Network I see that the file `delete.php` is called on button click and the `id: 1` is correct one.

This is my html part

```
<div class="comment-head">
    <i class="fa fa-trash del" data-id="'.$row['id'].'"></i>
</div>

$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".del").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "delete.php",
      method: "GET",
      data: { "id": $(this).data("id") },
      dataType: "html"
    }).done(function( msg ) {
      $( "#log" ).html( msg );
    }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
      alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    }); 
  });
});
```

The `delete.php`

```
$pdo = Database::connect();

if ( isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_POST['id']))  
{                   
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM gustbook where id = :id"); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    Database::disconnect();

}
```

I realize that this is kind of newbie question but please bear with me.

Comment: `isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_POST['id'])`? Are you sure you know what's this for?

Comment: I trust your JavaScript is inside <script> tags, yes?

Comment: @u_mulder, I'm not really sure.

Comment: Yes, it's inside script tag at the bottom of the page after `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

delete.php:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();

if ( isset($_GET['id'])))  
{                   
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM gustbook where id = :id"); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', (int)$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    Database::disconnect();

}
```

You are making an AJAX request with GET method and at server side, you are checking for both GET as well as POST methods. So there is no way the code from the if will get execute ever.

Update:

You have to convert $id to integer

Comment: Still same. Nothing happen. No errors and in console I under Network tab I see `Query String Parameters: id:2`

Comment: Do you have record with id 2 in gustbook table?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 test rows in table. Id 1 and id 2

Comment: Also write echo $_GET['id']; in delete.php and make sure you are getting id there and check your PDO connection

Comment: Where should I see this `echo $_GET['id'];`?

Comment: Yes, I see it in console under response `string(1) "2"` when I add `var_dump($_GET['id']);`

Comment: Is $id defined here? `$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: Yes, inside if I have `$id = $_GET['id'];`

Comment: Strange but when I move it outside if it's started to work

Comment: Okay, but you didn't show the $id being defined in your question